# How to fix fetch event in service worker using workbox.streams

Tags: workbox

I am using workbox.streams to try to combine data to create a response. The fetch event is not firing.

I'm working on understanding how `workbox.streams` work.

The code below is the third iteration. I thought that it was a problem with the regular expression so I changed that to what's in the code below.

I made sure that I was working with the latest version of Workbox to make sure it wasn't a problem with the version I was using.

I've also changed the precache for the files to eliminate that as the source of the problem.

```js
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.0.0-beta.0/workbox-sw.js');

// Make this a debug build
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
});

const HEAD = '/page-top.html';
const FOOT = '/page-bottom.html';
// const ERROR = '/page-error.html';

const cacheStrategy = workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
  cacheName: workbox.core.cacheNames.precache,
});

const networkStrategy = workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
  cacheName: 'content',
  plugins: [
    new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
      maxEntries: 50,
    }),
  ],
});

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('\.*\.html'),
  workbox.streams.strategy([
    () => cacheStrategy.makeRequest({request: HEAD}),
    async ({event}) => {
      try {
        const contentResponse = networkStrategy.makeRequest({
          request: event.request.url,
        });
        const contentData = await contentResponse.text();
        return contentData;
      } catch (error) {
        return cacheStrategy.makeRequest({request: ERROR});
      }
    },
    () => cacheStrategy.makeRequest({request: FOOT}),
  ])
);
```

I expect the browser to render the page made from all the components cached with `workbox.streams.strategy`.  Instead, I get only the body of the page; it appears that the entire route is ignored.

Comment: What does your precache manifest look like? Is there any chance that the URL you expect to be routed to the streams handler is already listed in the precache manifest? `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute()` is listed first, so it would take precedence.

Comment: I have cached inde.html and the components of the pages I want to stream. The files I want to stream are not pre-cached.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. `new RegExp('\\.html$')` might be a better RegExp to try. But in case that's not it, could you share a URL for a deployment of your web app that uses your current SW? I'll take a look and it should help with debugging.

Comment: I've changed the regular expression to the one you suggested... it still did not work. 

I put a simplified version of what I want to do at: https://caraya.github.io/streams-experiments/

Comment: Here's a diff showing the differences needed to get things working with Workbox v4: https://github.com/caraya/streams-experiments/compare/master...jeffposnick:master#diff-45510d615959be3a993aca672635aca5

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/jeffposnick/streams-experiments/ and try that as a starting point if you need.